# MS SQL table contains duplicate row values for one column but its values for other coumn are different, unique values of multiple entry?

Tags: sql-server-2005, duplicates

I have a table a which have multiple entry of artikelNr for it to contain multiple Enhet values just like in the picture below, I would like to query all the unique artikelNr which are not associated with Enhet=5.

There is another table which contains unique artikelNr only, if it can help. I am using MS SQL in my local database.

```
artikelNr enhet                      output should look like
  1         0                        artikelnr          enhet 
  1         5                          2                 0 or 3  no problem
  1         8                          6                 0 or 8 or 3 no problem 
  1         3
  2         0
  2         3 
  4         5  
  4         0  
  4         1  
  4         2
  6         8
  6         0
  6         3
  1         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Select distinct (artikelNr) from ArtAlias where artikelNr NOT IN 
    (select artikelNr from ArtAlias where enhet = 5) order by ArtikelNr
```

Comment: sorry my friend it just gets the unique artikelnr without checking the association of this artikelnr with enhet value as 5.

Comment: some help asap, it will be a lifesaver

Comment: @user1437417 I am not understanding you expected output. Where enhet <> 5 itself removes all artikelNr with the value 5. You mean artikelNr should not come in the output at all if he is associated with enhet=5 ? can you give expected output for your above table ?

Comment: ´Select distinct (artikelNr) from ArtAlias where artikelNr NOT IN (select artikelNr where enhet = 5) order by ArtikelNr´  i have tried it but does not check that association as well, getting the values associated with enhet=5 as well.

Comment: will some one help on this issue i am stuck, at this point, have been trying different ways not getting a result as wanted, some help would be appreciated.  i am new to databases so, some explanation as well would be helpful.

Comment: Query in your previous comment is wrong, check the edited answer.

Comment: @sudhakarthanks,  with some edits your answer worked for me, sorry for being so dumb. ´ Select distinct artikelNr from ArtAlias where ArtikelNr not in (select ArtikelNr from ArtAlias where Enhet=5)  order by ArtikelNr ´ this code worked for me now need go ahead.